# How to find out why Kubernetes dns-controller is not creating records for our own/company domain?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, external-dns

Our KOPS based Kubernetes cluster in AWS stopped creating external dns records in Route53 like: service-name-svc.testing.companydomain.com. Is there any way to check what flag is set for the dns-controller working within the cluster? Any other suggestions on how to troubleshoot it are welcomed!

With this in mind, the records like: service-name-svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local resolves fine.

```
Server:    100.32.0.10
Address 1: 100.32.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      service-name-svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local

Address 1: 100.32.12.141 service-name-svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of creating route53 records in a kOps cluster is to deploy [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) to the control plane nodes.

dns-controller may create route53 records too, and it does so for kube-apiserver and other system components. However, to use this for other nodes/services, you need to add specific annotations. See the [dns-controller documentation.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/dns-controller/README.md)